# Unable to display flash message using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel and i am working on laravel (version 8 ) trying to save "form data" into database,but i am faceing
following problems

1. How can i display flash message ? right now my "success" message is working fine but "error" message
   is not displaying
2. I just created "model" file,without define any "table" name in this file, but data is saving into database,is this right ? actually i want to know to purpose of "create model" because without mention "table" name,data is saving into database

Here is my controller code

```
   <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Students;
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    function addStudent(Request $req)
        {
                $Students= new Students;
                $Students->name=$req->name;
                $Students->email=$req->email;
                $Students->marks=$req->marks;
                $Students->address=$req->address;
                $saved=$Students->save();
                try
                    {
                        Students->save();
                    }
                catch(\Exception $e)
                    {
                        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error2' => 'something went wrong!']);
                    }
                return back()->with('success2','User created successfully!');
        }
}
```

Here is my view file

```
 @if (\Session::has('error2'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                    <strong>{!! \Session::get('msg') !!}</strong>
                </div>
                @endif
              
              <form class="forms-sample" action="addStudent" method="POST">
              @csrf
                    //my form code here
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i display flash message ? right now my "success" message is
> working fine but "error" message is not displaying

Instead of

```
return back()->with('error2','something went wrong!');
```

Try

```
function addStudent(Request $req)
    {
        $Students= new Students;
        $Students->name=$req->name;
        $Students->email=$req->email;
        $Students->marks=$req->marks;
        $Students->address=$req->address;
        try
        {
            $Students->save();
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            return back()->withErrors(['error2' => 'something went wrong!']);
        }
        return back()->with('success2','User created successfully!');
    }
```

and inside your view call this

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>{{ $errors->first() }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

If you want to get the single `error2` here then you can use

```
@if (\Session::has('error2'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <a href="#" class="close" data dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>{!! \Session::get('error2') !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

> I just created "model" file,without define any "table" name in this
> file, but data is saving into database,is this right ? actually i want
> to know to purpose of "create model" because without mention "table"
> name,data is saving into database

You don't need to define a table name in your because laravel can auto link your table to your model if you follow the laravel naming convention for naming your model and table. According to laravel if your model name is `User` then laravel will bind the table with name `users` to this model automatically without you defining the table name in the model that is table name should be plural of the model name and in all lower case.

In above case if you want to use the table name other than `users` then you will have to explicitly define the table name in the model so that laravel can bind this table to the model.

Comment: still not working i am getting following error message instead of flash message "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'abc@gmail.com' for key 'students_email_unique'

Comment: That's because your insert statement is throwing an exception and you will have to catch this exception. Let me update my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle the query exception

Comment: sorry but still not working , i am getting same error again

Comment: Can you update your code that what is your code now?

Comment: update my code now

Comment: ```$saved=$Students->save();``` Remove this line from your code

Comment: Also change this line from ```Students->save();``` to ```$Students->save();```

Comment: now i am getting following error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not found "

Comment: use this ```return back()->withErrors(['error2' => 'something went wrong!']);``` instead of ```return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error2' => 'something went wrong!']);```

Comment: If you still want to use ```Redirect``` then you will have to import ```Redirect```  using this statement ```use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;```

Comment: Just a useful tip for you that is to try to use PHPStorm as your code editor as it offers many other benefits one of which is it will also automatically resolve most of the imports for you so that you don't run into these kinds of Classes not found issues again

Comment: Let me know if you face any other issue or it is resolved now?